# Issue translating validation messages in formidable form in concrete 5

Tags: concrete5, formidable

I used "Translate Site Interface" to translate the text for the submit button (marked in blue) to German but for translating validation messages (marked in red) it is not working, even though I used the same process to translate. To view the screenshot of the form please see the link below.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDseX.pngstrong]

Comment: Are you using one of the formidable form addons (https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/formidable-full-version or https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/formidable-lite)?

Comment: Yes, I am using concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/formidable-full-version.

Comment: Then I think it is best to question the developers of this addon on the related support page, see: https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/formidable-full-version/support.

Comment: I did add a support ticket for this issue, about 10 days ago, but there was no response yet.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I also see that the do not answer open questions/tickets. Maybe you have to contact them by email, see: https://www.dewebmakers.nl/contact/. There is a form and also an info address `info@dewebmakers.nl`. I really hope you get an answer! Otherwise add a further comment here.

Comment: Sure, I will email them regarding the issue and thanks for your support.